# How can I bump the version in my phonegap application for google play?

Tags: cordova, google-play, phonegap-build

I have tried researching this myself but nothing seems to be working.
[I keep getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk1M9.png)
I've bumped the version in the config to 1.2.0
I've tried going into my Android-manifest and bumping the version code to 10200
But nothing is working.
Im using phonegap build to sign the app and using github to push the app to phonegap build. 
BTW phonegap build reconizes that i bumped the version up
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are three version values you should be aware of in Cordova:

1. version
2. android-versionCode
3. ios-CFBundleVersion

These three attributes are all in the `config.xml` and should be place in the `widget` node. The last two are platform specific, so in your case you should only worry about 1 & 2. Verify that `version` & `android-versionCode` are both correct and are transferring properly to your AndroidManifest.xml at build time. Make sure those versions values are not less that a previous value you already included in an app submission to Google Play.